# Javascript to add row in html table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In the below code i have html table in which i need to add row to html table  and insert into database .But I couldn't add row.Pls help me to rectify the issue.My aim is to avoid postback so i choose javascript to add row .

```
<script language="javascript">        
  function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById("<%=dataTable.ClientID%>").value;
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
      switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
      }
  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
      var table = document.getElementById("<%=dataTable.ClientID%>");
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
          var row = table.rows[i];
          var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
          if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
              if (rowCount <= 1) {
                  alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                  break;
              }
              table.deleteRow(i);
              rowCount--;
              i--;
          }
      }
  } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
  }
}
</script>



  <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"/>

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"/>

    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txt" runat="server"/></td>
            <td>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You provide your `document.getElementById` with a server generated `id`, and also pass `tableID` to the function. Seems redundant.

Comment: @Mouser i just copy the view source and paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses lines are the problem:

```
var table = document.getElementById("<%=dataTable.ClientID%>").value;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

Correct them to this:

```
var tableBody = document.getElementById("<%=dataTable.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var row = tableBody .insertRow(rowCount);
```

Rows are inserted in a `tablebody` (`tbody`) and/or a `tablehead` (`thead`).

`var table = document.getElementById("<%=dataTable.ClientID%>").value` will return `undefined`. The value attribute is used only on inputs to retrieve or set the content of an input.

Comment: Yes Fine and how to insert the values into DB on clicking Save Button using C#?

Comment: Was not part of your original question. But either wrap the values  in a form with inputs or use an AJAX call. Post the values to your aspx file.

Comment: The table row disappear if i select dropdown values

Comment: I don't know what your auto post back value does? Maybe it refreshes the page?